# Showing that $3^{(3^n - 1)}$ divides $(3^n)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am trying to solve the following by using induction:

> Show that $3^{(3^n - 1)}$ divides $(3^n)!$ for any non-negative integer $n$.

But isn't the question incorrect, since it doesn't hold for $n=1$, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right.$  $

Comment: It does not work for $n = 2$ either, and obviously reversing the two values will not work, so this problem is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid that the problem is incorrect.

The highest power of 3 that devides $(3^n)!$ is $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \left\lfloor \frac { 3^{ n } }{ 3^{ i } }  \right\rfloor  } $, which is equal to $\frac { 3^{ n }-1 }{ 2 } $.

The proof to the general highest power of $p$ when p is a prime number that divides $n$! can be seen 
[here](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/NumberTh10FactorialDivisors.aspx).